# MySQL query to get data of child and master table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have two tables named `order` and `orderdetail` with a relation on key `order_id`
I want to query the database to fetch a grand total per order.

The `order` table has fields `order_id`, `customer_name` etc.

The `order_detail` table has fields `id (primary key)`, `order_number (foreign key)`, `product`, `qty`, `price`

I would like a result with fields like this:

`order_id`, `grand_total`.

I created a view for `order_detail` like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW orderTotal AS
SELECT
    order_number,
    Round(sum(qty * price),2) as grandTotal
    FROM order_detail t group by order_number;
```

It works pretty well, but there is an issue. Some orders has no reference data in `order_detail`, and then that record is not listed by this view. How can I solve this? Please give me a sample query.

It may need multiple SQL queries, but can we build it as a view?

As an example, I need data like this:

```
order_id    grandTotal
1           200
2           0                    // when data is missing
3           150.35
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have parent records and no children, it could help you:

```
SELECT
order.order_id,
coalesce(Round(sum(order_detail.qty * order_detail.price),2),0) as grandTotal
FROM order 
LEFT join order_detail on order_detail.order_number = order.order_id 
GROUP BY order.order_id
```